# JPA: Use a multiple One-to-many relationships with composite keys

Tags: java, mysql, sql, hibernate, jpa

I have these entities:

`Run` entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "run")
@JsonIdentityInfo(generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class, 
property = "runId")
public class Run implements Serializable {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "run_id")
    private Long runId;

    @Column(name = "status")
    private Integer status;

    @Column(name = "create_date")
    private Date date;

    @Column(name = "config_id")
    private Long configId;

    @Column(name = "stream_id")
    private Long streamId;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "run", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    @JoinColumn(name = "run_id", unique = true, nullable = true, insertable = true, updatable = true)
    private StreamRun streamRun;
    ...
}
```

and `StreamRun` entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "stream_run")
@JsonIdentityInfo(generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class, 
property = "streamId")
public class StreamRun implements Serializable {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long streamId;

    @Column(name = "run_id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private Long runId;

    @Column(name = "stream_name")
    private String streamName;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "run_id")
    private Run run;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "stream", orphanRemoval = true, targetEntity = JobRun.class)
    private List<JobRun> jobs = new ArrayList<>();

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "streamRun", orphanRemoval = true, targetEntity = StreamEvent.class)
    private List<StreamEvent> events = new ArrayList<>();

    ....
    }
```

and `JobRun` entity:

```
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "jobs_run")
    @JsonIdentityInfo(generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class, 
    property = "id")
    @IdClass(JobRunKey.class)
    public class JobRun implements Serializable {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "run_id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private Long runId;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "type")
    private String jobType;

    @Column(name = "script")
    private String script;

    @Column(name = "status")
    private Integer status;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumns({ @JoinColumn(name = "run_id", referencedColumnName = "run_id"), @JoinColumn(name = "job_stream_id", referencedColumnName = "id") })
    private StreamRun stream;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "jobRun", orphanRemoval = true, targetEntity = JobDependencyRun.class)
    public List<JobDependencyRun> dependencies = new ArrayList<>();

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "jobRun", orphanRemoval = true, targetEntity = JobEvent.class)
    public List<JobEvent> events = new ArrayList<>();

    ....
}
```

And all the columns are defined in the MySQL database, Table `job_run` have composite key of (`id` and `run_id`).

The problem is in `JobRun` entity:

- If I define "run_id" field as `@ID` then an exception appear (when insert)

  > Parameter index out of range (8 > number of parameters, which is 7).
- If I define it without `@ID` then an exception appear (when update)

  > Duplicate entry '4-78' for key 'PRIMARY'
- If I remove the whole field definition from entity since it is foreign key then the exception will be:

  > Unable to find column with logical name `run_id`

  "Although the column exists in the table".

Please, can anyone help me?
Do I do anything wrong in the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have managed to find a solution, by modifying `JobRun` entity as below, and change\access the value of `runId` from direct setter and getter method.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "jobs_run")
@JsonIdentityInfo(generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class, 
property = "id")
@IdClass(JobRunKey.class)
public class JobRun implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "run_id")
    private Long runId;

    @Column(name = "job_stream_id")
    private Long streamId;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "type")
    private String jobType;

    @Column(name = "script")
    private String script;

    @Column(name = "status")
    private Integer status;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumns({ @JoinColumn(name = "run_id", referencedColumnName = "run_id", insertable = false, updatable = false),
            @JoinColumn(name = "job_stream_id", referencedColumnName = "id", insertable = false, updatable = false) })
    private StreamRun stream;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "jobRun", orphanRemoval = true, targetEntity = JobDependencyRun.class)
    public List<JobDependencyRun> dependencies = new ArrayList<>();

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "jobRun", orphanRemoval = true, targetEntity = JobEvent.class)
    public List<JobEvent> events = new ArrayList<>();
    ...
}
```